# Fastest Way to Determine User Permissions in /etc/sudoer

Tags: linux, permissions, ssh, sudoers

Users will be remotely accessing ***nix based machines via SSH and I need to determine the *fastest* way to check if the username that they are currently using has NOPASSWD access in the /etc/sudoers file.

Possible options:

- grep for the username in /etc/sudoers, parse command prompt output to determine if it has NOPASSWD, if not, remove the line then append the new permissions
- Just append a permission string to the file regardless (bad idea).
- Attempt to sudo into a protected file and see if it prompts me for a password.

I'm hoping for something easier, but my google-fu hasn't come up with any answers.

Comment: Would have asked it on "Super User" but I'm not currently in the beta. Not sure if this even relates more to Server Fault than here; doesn't "fit" anywhere really...

Comment: @Hawker: Super User is in 'semi-private beta'. You can get access without hassle. Look here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/super-user-semi-private-beta-begins/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `sudo -v` succeeds, the user has been authorized to use `sudo`; if it fails, then the user has not been authorized to use `sudo`.

```
# su user -c 'setsid sudo -v </dev/null'; echo $?
[sudo] password for user:
1
# su root -c 'setsid sudo -v </dev/null'; echo $?
0
```

Without [setsid](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setsid), `sudo` will try to ask for the password interactively even if stdin/stdout/stderr have all been redirected.  If you don't have a controlling terminal, this isn't needed, but you will probably need something other than `su` to change user permissions, like [fork](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork)+[setreuid](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setreuid).

Answer (score 1):

If you indeed need "the *fastest* way", I guess you're building a webserver that would handle many concurrent requests.

This raises another problem - the concurrency issue. Generally, many process reading and writing to the same important file is a recipe for a catastrophe.

Build a small independent process to handle the task. It should have a minimal interface that will receive requests from the clients, and updates for the the `/etc/sudoer` file. Something like `has_NOPASSWD_access()` and `set_NOPASSWD_access()`. It should read the file only when it needs to be written, so you'll greatly reduce the I/O time required to serve a request.

Pros -

- Fast : No I/O needed for just reading the file, because it is stored in the buffer since the initial read
- Thread safe: Only one server writes and reads the sudoer file
- [Single choice principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_choice_principle) - only this process handles the sudoer file
- Elegant (I hope) :-)

Cons -
 - List them in the comments, and I'll add.