# Check if a user is root

Tags: php, linux, root

How can i verify if a user is root in a PHP script ? What is the command ?
I tried something like that :

```
exec("su -l login < `echo password`");
```

but the su command can not receive password...

Note that the machine is isolated from internet so I can run PHP as root if needed.

EDIT: 
I don't want to know if the current user who run the script is root or not.
**I have a list of users in my PHP script and I want to know for each login if he has root privileges.**

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Perhaps exec("su -l login < " . $password) ?

Comment: You can try and see if the command 'whoami' is present.

Comment: In a PHP script I want to know if a login/password have administrator privileges. The login/password is not the user who execute the PHP script.

Comment: If you want to check if a login is superuser, then `$username=="root"` is the obvious choice. I guess what you are actually asking is if the user is in the sudoers group. Not sure if there is a deterministic method for that. Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133364/fastest-way-to-determine-user-permissions-in-etc-sudoer - But better ask on Unix.SE -- If your issue is just piping the password in, try proc_open instead of a plain exec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, ask yourself what exactly defines a login "having root privileges". AFAICT there are 2 basic solutions.

The old-school way, where sysadmins create multiple accounts with uid 0, which I - and I'm certainly not alone in this - consider to be a nightmare. In this scenario you could check all users in your list using [posix_getpwnam](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-getpwnam.php) and see if their uid matches 0.

The following code snippet does just that, $privileged will contain the users with root privileges :

```
$logins = array('root', 'john', 'guest', 'foo');
$privileged = array();
foreach($logins as $login) {
    $userInfo = posix_getpwnam($login);
    if ($userInfo !== FALSE) {
        if ($userInfo['uid'] == 0) {
          $privileged[] = $login;
        }
    }
}
```

The other (and imho only sane) way to do this is to add all users with root/administrative privileges to a specific group (*wheel* or *admin* are already used in different Linux distributions, find out which one works for you). This scenario is even simpler, since you can use [posix_getgrnam](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-getgrnam.php) to fetch all members in a specific group.

The following code snippet will match an array of logins you provide, and see who's a member with specific privileges, again $privileged will contain the result (ie. the users in your list that are a member of the group you specified) :

```
$logins = array('root', 'john', 'guest', 'foo');
$privileged = array();
$groupInfo = posix_getgrnam('admins');
if ($groupInfo !== FALSE) {
    $privileged = array_intersect($logins, $groupInfo['members']);
}
```

Comment: I put my users in "adm" group and use posix_getgrnam() to get informations. Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

How about [`posix_getuid()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-getuid.php)?

```
if (0 == posix_getuid()) {
    echo "Running as root.";
} else {
    echo "not root";
}
```

Comment: I don't want to know if the user who run the script is root or no. I have to check in a PHP script for some login/password if they are root or not

Comment: @scrat I don't understand. That's what the example does. It checks the *real user ID* of the script running; the UID for root is usually 0 (zero).

Comment: @goreSplatter I have a list of users in my PHP script and I want to know for each login if he has root privileges.

Comment: @scrat While I think of an answer, you might consider putting your last comment into the question. It'll make it **a lot** easier to answer.

Comment: @scrat789: There should be only one *real* root (with uid 0), so shouldn't you just check if they are a member of a specific group (administrators, sudoers or the like)?

Comment: @wimvds That is incorrect. *root* is not the Highlander. `useradd -s /bin/bash -ou 0 foobert` will give you a fresh user with root privileges.

Comment: @goreSplatter: I know, I've seen some admins do just that, but for me (and I guess any sysadmin who wants to keep his/her sanity) using groups makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @wimvds Definitely. I didn't say it's good practice. Only that it's possible.

Comment: @wimvds "using groups makes a lot more sense." It can be a partial solution. Can I verify a user password in PHP ?

Comment: @scrat789: Check my answer first :p.

Comment: More info: https://superuser.com/questions/626843/does-the-root-account-always-have-uid-gid-0

Answer (score 3):

Try This .

```
<?php
    if (posix_getuid() == 0){
        echo "This is root !";
        // add more for root
    } else {
        echo "This is non-root";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Rewritten after your comment

> "I don't want to know if the user who
> run the script is root or no. I have
> to check in a PHP script for some
> login/password if they are root or
> not"

I now understood that you need to perform a **root authentication** in PHP.

I suggest to use `pwauth` instead of whoami/login, etc.

[Here](http://www.zeentan.com/wp/?p=73) is an example on how to use it from PHP, while I believe there can be a simpler way of testing.

Answer (score 1):

If you really mean "is root", then you can just check for `whoami`, and see if it comes up 'root'

```
exec("whoami");
```

If it's a smart thing to do is a different question ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see if a certain *system* user (as opposed to a web-service user) has root priviliedges, you can use the [`posix_getpwnam()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-getpwnam.php) function:

```
<?php
    $u = posix_getpwnam("username");

    if ($u == FALSE) {
        print "no-such-user";
    } elseif ($u["uid"] == 0) {
        print "root";
    } else {
        print "non-root";
    };
?>
```

Keep in mind that this only checks the username. If you also need to check the password you actually have to try to authenticate with the system.

Comment: That's an interresting function but when I tried, I got an uid > 0 even if I am sure the login is an superuser..

Comment: @scrat789: then you have to share with us what your definition of "superuser" is. How would you determine if an account is "superuser" e.g. from a bash shell?

Comment: @scrat789: On most Unix-like systems a superuser account is an account with UID=0. Normally there is only one such account ("root"), although some administrators install aditional aliases ("operator", "sysop") for that UID for legacy compatibility reasons.

Comment: in shell, when I run "echo $UID" after "su -l login" command I got 0 (that I want). But before the su, my UID is 500 like the output of the posix_getpwnam function.

Comment: @scrat789: you have to replace the "username" in `posix_getpwnam()` with the username that you want to check, not your own.