# PHP: How to detect if user is root/sudo?

Tags: php, linux, root, sudo

I have a command line PHP script that needs to be run with root-level permissions on Linux systems.

On our old, old Redhat Enterprise 2 Linux distro, this code worked:

```
// If we are linux, make sure we're root
if ($bIsLinux && $_ENV['USER'] != 'root')
    die("This script must be run as root.\n");
```

However, we've upgraded servers and are now on a modern version of linux (Amazon Linux). Which is great, but the above no longer works. On AML, you don't actually have the root password, but you can sudo from `ec2-user`. I've even tried `sudo -i` but that doesn't change the environment variable - and thus the above code fails.

So I need a new way to ensure root-level privileges before continuing.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at this question? [Check if a user is root](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713574/check-if-a-user-is-root)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using [posix_getuid](https://www.php.net/posix_getuid) you can check if a user is root.

```
<?php
    if (posix_getuid() === 0){
        echo "This is root !";
    } else {
        echo "This is non-root";
}
?>
```

`0` is root, anything else is not.

Comment: please don't use `== 0` tho, if you get an error during checking and it returns FALSE or NULL, it will still be considered `0-ish` and say "root". use `=== 0` here

Comment: On PHP (with sudo command) implement $_SERVER environment is

$_SERVER['SUDO_USER'], $_SERVER['SUDO_GID'] ,$_SERVER['SUDO_UID']

That means, where contains 'SUDO_XX' it maybe run as "sudo"

Answer (score 5):

Try https://www.php.net/posix_getuid and check if it returns zero. If so it is root. If not is is some other user